# Verb to describe what merchants do in country-side fairs

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

I am looking for a verb that would describe what merchants do in Fairs. Like this one :

[image: A fair]

I find "trade" too formal considering what I need. I am looking for something in the idea of *showcasing* thingsn *interacting* with people, *polishing* products, *taking care of the stands*. Something conceptually almost as vague as *to work* but more pointed to this kind of activity.

Comment: They display and sell their wares. Could you provide  a sample sentence that shows how you would use the term, leaving a blank where it would go? Thanks.

Comment: It is for the title of a section in a document relating to Fairs, there would only be this word, no sentence around it =/ I see what your question is, but I don't even see how to fit it in a phrase in a way that would make my meaning clearer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He sounds like a [**hawker**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hawker):

> A person who travels about selling goods, typically advertising them by shouting. *hawkers and costermongers pushed their little handcarts, crying ‘Bread!’, ‘Fish!’ and ‘Meat pies!’* (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

Comment: I love it, amazingly suited to the fair thematic

Comment: *Pedlar* is similar: the technical difference is that they are on foot while hawkers have carts.

Comment: @red2nb - **hawker** is a noun, you said you were looking for a verb, which is of course **[to hawk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hawk?q=hawking#hawk-2)**. At a fair, the merchants are **hawking** their wares.

Answer (score 5):

Peddle. They peddle their wares.

"try to sell (something, especially small goods) by going from place to place"

Answer (score 3):

You can say they ***[market](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/market):***

> - (v. int.) to deal in a market; engage in buying or selling.

(AHD)

Comment: Very interesting ! I'll check if there's a synonym, the only problem I see with this word, is that I feel that in our modern society, when people read market, they can think of so many different thing (marketing, stock exchange, etc...) I'd like to keep them in a certain state of mind related to fairs

Comment: I see, consider that the original meaning is: ***Market:***  early 12c., "a meeting at a fixed time for buying and selling livestock and provisions," . ***to market***: 1630s, from market (n.).

Answer (score 2):

I think ***vend*** is closest to what you are looking for.  People who sell at fairs are known as ***vendors***.  Vend encompasses all activities involved with setting up a stall and selling wares at a fair.

[From Oxforddictionaries.com:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vend)

> Offer (small items, especially food) for sale, especially either from
>   a stall or from a slot machine.

Answer (score 1):

**tout**, the merchants **tout** for business.

The word **tout** is like **hawk** but has slight connotations of shameless desperation

Answer (score 0):

Merchants may **expose** or **exhibit** goods, i.e. offer or expose to view.

> Examples: The storekeeper exposed his wares. The latest models of cars
>   were exhibited in Detroit Auto Show.

A pitchman or a street peddler also **makes commerce**.

> "Commerce" refers to activities that relate to the buying and selling
>   of goods and services, and also to social intercourse (e.g.
>   interchange of ideas, opinions, or sentiments).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **huckster**.

> (n) huckster: retailer of small articles; a hawker; a peddler; now, especially, a small dealer in agricultural produce.
>
> (v) huckster: to expose for sale; make a matter of bargain.
>
> ([**Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia**](http://www.finedictionary.com/huckster.html))

Alternately, **pitchman** might fit the context just as well.

> pitch: to attempt to sell or win approval for; promote; advertise: *to pitch cereals at a sales convention.* ([**Random House**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch))
>
> pitchman: someone who travels about [**vending**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vend) their wares (as on the streets or at carnivals) ([**Free Dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitchman))